# Use regex with xpath evaluate to look through every date

Tags: php, regex, xpath

I'm trying to get every item with the same ID, even though they don't have the same date.

For example, I input the ID `41` and it would then find the matching item(s) from the document which has the following items:

```
    <item>
      <name>Abc</name>
      <id>41:2021-10-12</id>
    </item>
    <item>
      <name>Bca</name>
      <id>41:2021-10-13</id>
    </item>
    <item>
      <name>Def</name>
      <id>42:2021-10-12</id>
    </item>
    <item>
      <name>Fed</name>
      <id>42:2021-10-13</id>
    </item>
```

This is what I've tried:

```
$trainIdDate = $trainId.':/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/';
if ($xpath->evaluate("count(self::*[id = '$trainIdDate']) > 0", $item)) {
```

It works fine if I do:

```
$trainIdDate = $trainId.':2021-10-12';
if ($xpath->evaluate("count(self::*[id = '$trainIdDate']) > 0", $item)) {
```

Comment: You should give a sample of your XML data

Comment: I would just convert to array and explode `id` by `:` (limited). Or substring by strpos of `:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider the the id a string starting with the train ID followed by a colon.

```
$trainID = 42;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$expression = "//item[starts-with(id, '$trainID:')]";
foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $item) {
    var_dump(
        [
            $xpath->evaluate('string(name)', $item),
            $xpath->evaluate('string(id)', $item),
        ]
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

XPath 1.0 has no support for regular expressions.

With XPath 2.0+ you can do

```
count(self::*[matches(id, '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}]') > 0
```

but the default XPath engine for PHP only supports 1.0.

Comment: It is possible to emulate some of it with callbacks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55750848/partial-matching-using-xpath/55777340#55777340